# Second store not showing new URL links

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm using Magento 1.9 and have set up a second store following the instructions here - https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains

When I go to domain2.com, it looks normal but all of the links on the page point to domain1.com.  Do I need to do something so all of my links are for domain2.com?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you done a reindex yet?

Comment: @StevenJ 'Catalog URL Rewrites' says processing and is taking forever, but SOME of the links are now pointing to domain2.com! Know of any way to speed up Catalog URL Rewrites reindexing? Thanks!

Comment: Are you reindexing from the admin panel or via SSH? I prefer SSH since it gives times it took to complete. You can use `/usr/local/php55/bin/php-cli -f shell/indexer.php reindexall` to trigger reindexing from SSH

Comment: Thanks! Reindexing completed.  Most links are domain1.com, some sets of menu links are domain2.com. Any idea where to look to change it?

Comment: That depends on if the links are hardcoded to the domain or if they use the short code for the domain. It's best practice to use `<a href="{{store url="link-text"}}">link text </a>` so that the links will auto-update when being viewed from a different store view or domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making changes like this, it's important to do a full reindex. It shouldn't be needed more than once - but it's good to have the reindex process setup on a cron job. Depending on how busy your store is, and the size of your product and category catalog should help you decide how often you need this cron job to run.

If you have Cron Jobs setup, you can use this string to trigger the Reindex. This particular timing is for ever 2 hours. This should work globally but can be modified to use a particular folder if needed.

```
0 */2 * * * /usr/local/php55/bin/php-cli -f shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

Also, it's best practice to use the `{{store url=""}}` short code inside of the `href` tag so that the base URL will update when being viewed from another store view and/or website domain.

For example:

```
<p>Check out <a href="{{store url="awesome-page"}}">awesome page</a>.</p>
```

In a last-ditch effort to correct any issues - you could, **but probably shouldn't**, truncate your entire `core_url_rewrite` table via phpMyAdmin. Doing this will cause the entire link structure to be reindexed and built from scratch. This can definitely have adverse effects - so as always - make a backup of your DB or test on Staging first.

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to `admin>system>configuration>select your domaine2 website scope in a top left corner>general>web>secure and not secure section>uncheck "Use default Value" then set your new domaine2 url>Save`

2- Reindex all and clear your Magento and Browser cache.